# Server (socket) overload with Marionette / Backbone app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm a new coder learning Marionette to make a meeting booker app. I've asked around and banged my head for hours already.

Basically, the issue is this, when I add a meeting, new additional ones are created randomly and causes the server to overload. I was wondering if this has to do with some sort of loop or memory leak that I'm not aware of in my setup.

**Here's the code for creating meetings:**
https://github.com/jdaudier/meeting-booker/blob/master/public/javascripts/app.js

A short video of the bug:  screencast.com/t/3rHIqPm07F

Images of the bug:

http://screencast.com/t/feN5sbZBWzHe

screencast.com/t/Yuzys5Xizu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there isn't anything wrong with the client side code. You're server code, on the other hand, has a subtle bug in it that is causing the browser to behave badly.

In the /routes/meeting.js file, line 83 - 89:

```
    meeting.save(function(err){
        if(!err){
          return console.log('created a new meeting:', meeting.title);
        } else {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        return res.send(meeting);
    });
```

You are never returning a response from this method because you have a `return` statement in both conditions of the `if` check. Therefore, the browser never sees a response and waits for about 90 seconds (i think) before it barfs on the AJAX call.

The reason this fails at 6 attempts is because you've hit the browser limit of 5 open network connections.

The fix is to remove the unwanted `return` on logging the `created a new meeting` message.

```
    meeting.save(function(err){
        if(err){
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('created a new meeting:', meeting.title);
        return res.send(meeting);
    });
```

With this fix in place, the browser gets the appropriate 200 OK response from the server, and closes the connection. I was able to run through ~15 meeting adds with no issues after putting this fix in the server code.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Does this mean Addy Osmani had the same bug in his Backbone book since I copied the code line-for-line?
http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#marionettejs-backbone.marionette

Comment: I submitted a pull request to update the 2 bugs in Addy's book: https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals/pull/572/files